# Jquery Offset returns different values when refreshing the site

Tags: jquery, css

I'm useing offset() in function that makes clocks needle rotates and points at mouse.
The problem is that the needle some times point at mosue and somtimes not.
The differents I'v discoverd is that the offset return diferent values when I refresh the browser
(when testing mouse is oudside the browser and I do not touch it's size).
Do you have a solution or ida why it's happening?

```
 <div class="clock">
   <div id="apDiv3" class="opening">
     <div class="clock">
       <img id="apDiv2" class="clock" src="./assets/stoper-01.png" usemap="#image-map">
       <img id="apDiv1" class="clockArrow" src="./assets/stoper-01-arrow.png?">
                   
       <map name="image-map">
         <!-- a lot of <area> settins -->
       </map>

   </div>
```

```
div.clock {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

img.clock {
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  animation: stRotate 6s ease;
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
}
/* stRotate animation settings not much but small rotation*/

.clockArrow {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
}
```

```
let img = $(".clockArrow");
let offset = img.offset();

//console.log(offset);

function mouse(){

  img = $(".clockArrow");
  offset = img.offset();

  var center_x = (offset.left) + (img.width()/2);
  var center_y = (offset.top) + (img.height()/2);
  var mouse_x = evt.pageX; var mouse_y = evt.pageY;
  var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - center_x, mouse_y - center_y);
  var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 180; 

  }
}
$(document).mousemove(mouse);
```

Comment: Have you checked for cumulative layout shifts?

Comment: Bacause of some reasons  jQuery offset() doesn't cooperate with flex. Remove it form css should help